# How to achieve this responsiveness (im only asking about the circle users)?

Tags: css, sass, responsive-design, media-queries

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I want to achieve this responsiveness, I know how to make the horizontal and the vertical layout, my only concern is the 2 row layout one, first two elements in the first row and the 3rd element in the "middle" of the 2nd row, thats where im stuck with.

Comment: Please update with the HTML and CSS that you have tried so we may help you fix it

Comment: If none of the supplied answers answer your question please update your question with the requested HTML and CSS you are working with.  Otherwise please accept the best answer (click the check by it) that works and upvote any others you find useful.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `flex` like the other answer, I offer to use the well known `text-align: center` friend with `display: inline-block`.

```css
.circle {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container {
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}

.container.b {
  width: 120px;
}

.container.c {
  width: 240px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>

<div class="container b">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>


<div class="container c">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) can handle this reasonably well.

Html

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/200" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/tech/200/200" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/kids/200/200" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  animation: breathe 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
}

@keyframes breathe {
 0% {
  width: 150px;
 }

 100% {
  width: 500px;
 }
}
```

```html
<html>
 <body>    
    <div class="container">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/200" />
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/tech/200/200" />
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/kids/200/200" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then when your container expands, it will similarly shift your profile circles.

Example: https://codepen.io/iamredseal/pen/NWMxZKP

Comment: I took liberty to make a snippet of the code in your answer

Answer (score 0):

I took a stab at this with some flexbox style; I put borders on just to show where things were. Display this full screen then zoom it bigger then try some shrink of the page/display to see when your outer container gets more narrow, the bottom wraps below, then the middle if you make it more narrow.  Just add more `block-person` chunks to see this with more wrapping when you have many like 8 or 10;

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: solid 2px #4444aa;
}

.block-person {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: middle;
  margin: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid #88AAAA;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

.circle {
  align-self: center;
  border: solid #ff8888;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  width: 2.5em;
}

.person-name {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  margin: 0.5em;
}

.block-person {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block-person">
    <div class="circle">A</div>
    <span class="person-name">Apple</span>
  </div>
  <div class="block-person">
    <div class="circle">B</div>
    <span class="person-name">Barny Cow</span>
  </div>
  <div class="block-person">
    <div class="circle">C</div>
    <span class="person-name">Charlie Baker</span>
  </div>
</div>
```